# How can I pass a selected option from a dropdown menu to a new page in PHP?

Tags: php, html, redirect, parameters

This is my html for the search bar and dropdown.

```
<form action='seniorProjectLanding.php' method='POST' class='form-group'>
            <div class="form-horizontal" align="center">
              <input type="text" name="searchResults" 
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Search"
                style="width:80%; max-width:80%; display:inline-block"/>

              <button type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-primary"
                name="submit"
                style="margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-2px; min-height:36px;">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="row" align="center">
              <div class="form-group" style="width: 50%" align="center">
                <select id="dropdownForm" name="sortDropdown" class="form-control">
                  <option value="Name">Item Name</option>;
                  <option value="LocationID">Location</option>;
                  <option value="CategoryID">Category</option>;
                  <option value="Quantity">Quantity</option>;
                  <option value="LastQuantityUpdate">Most Recently Updated</option>;
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

And this is the PHP.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

  $searchResults = $_POST["searchResults"];
  $dropdownSelection = $_GET["dropdownForm"];

  if ($searchResults !== "") {
    header("Location: test2.php?sortBy=".$dropdownSelection."&searchResults=".$searchResults);
  }
  else {
    header("Location: test2.php?sortBy=".$dropdownSelection);
  }
```

}

I have gotten this to work using the input from a search box, but cannot seem to get it to work with this dropdown menu and its selected option values.

Comment: Need a submit button or some JavaScript to submit on selection change.

Comment: Your dropdown appears to be in one form and your submit button in another.

Comment: yeah i already had one but did not feel the need to post that code because the page is redirecting correctly upon pressing submit, it is just not passing the selection from the dropdown. I added it though to bypass any confusion.

Comment: As @iainn pointed out, you have two forms on your page. One with the select list and one with the submit button. When you click the submit button, only the form it's in will be posted. Every form needs their own submit buttons (or js that submits it some other way).

Comment: So if it works for the search bar, and I put the search bar and dropdown inside the same form with the same submit button, it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a submit button...

Defines a submit button (for submitting the form).

`<input type="submit">` defines a button for submitting the form data to a form-handler.

The form-handler is typically a server page with a script for processing input data.

The form-handler is specified in the form's action attribute.

Try using:

```
<form action="test1.php" method="POST" class="form-group">
        <div class="row" align="center">
          <div class="form-group" style="width: 50%" align="center">
            <select id="dropdownForm" name="sortDropdown" class="form-control">
              <option value="Name">Item Name</option>;
              <option value="LocationID">Location</option>;
              <option value="CategoryID">Category</option>;
              <option value="Quantity">Quantity</option>;
              <option value="LastQuantityUpdate">Most Recently Updated</option>;
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit

Answer (score 0):

If you’re wanting to add parameters to the query string, you want to use a form with a GET `method` instead. Then when you submit the form, its data will be added to the query string (i.e. for filtering/sorting search results):

```html
<form action="test1.php" method="GET">
  <select name="sort_by">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <!-- and so on -->
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will submit to **test1.php?sort_by=name** if the name option is selected.

You can add more fields as required. You’d also then access the values using `$_GET` instead:

```php
$sort_by = $_GET['sort_by'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are posting but are trying to access a get variable.  Also, you are using the control id `dropdownForm` and not the name `sortDropdown`:

```
$dropdownSelection = $_GET["dropdownForm"];
```

Should be:

```
$dropdownSelection = $_POST["sortDropdown"];
```

Using error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Would have given you this:

> Notice: Undefined index: dropdownForm in /path/to/file.php on line X

Comment: Yup. This what it! Just a simple case of using the wrong variable I guess. Thanks!